# Internal bool parameter with default value still required when running report

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, default-value

In SQL Server Reporting Services report I had a bool parameter `@IsCopy`. We decided, that this parameter wont be needed. Instead of deleting parameter and modifying all places, where it is used, I decided to change it to internal and add default value of `false`.

However, after I performed those step I can no longer open report (I can open it only from designer → preview), because of an error:

> Parameter 'IsCopy' not specified

What am I missing?

Comment: @Jeroen, seems a likely duplicate, though I suppose it can't be definitively proven until the solution is confirmed. I've voted to close, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, it's working from BIDS but not working after it's deployed?

When you deploy a report that replaces an existing one on the Report Server, any default values that have been set up are NOT overwritten.

So maybe what's happening is that even though you've updated the parameter and it's all working fine in the designer, when you deploy it since the parameter already exists it doesn't update it with a new default value as you require.

To test, after you've deployed an updated version of your report, I would double-check the default values associated with the report through Report Manager. Update the Report Server default value and see if this allows the report to run.

**Edit after comment:**

Onec a report has been deployed, in the Report Manager website **Manage** the report and check the Parameters:

[image]

You need to check the **Default Value** setting and anything else that needs to be updated.

Comment: Hi, could you explain this in some more detail. I am like jus starting with SSRS. What do you mean by "updating default values". Where are those stored and why those are not part of report itselft?

Comment: I have added a screenshot and some more information. The excellent answer provided by @Jeroen in the link he added has further detail, too.